# Aggregate multiple actor responses?

Tags: scala, akka

I am trying to collect health information for my application as

```
class HealthMonitor extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  val statusReporter = new StatusReporter
  val versionInfo = context.actorOf(Props[VersionInfo], "versionInfo")
  val memoryInfo = context.actorOf(Props[MemoryInfo], "memoryInfo")

  def receive = LoggingReceive {
    case HealthReportRequest => log.debug("Generating Health Report")
      println("Generating Health Report")
      // todo (harit): should be concurrent calls and collect results
      versionInfo ! VersionInfoRequest
      memoryInfo ! MemoryInfoRequest
  }
}
```

**What I need**
I need a way wherein I can collect responses from `versionInfo`, `memoryInfo`, and some other info later into 1 response and send it somewhere

and I do not want a sequential or want to block the calls, what is the best way?

Comment: Do an ask (?) instead of a tell (!) and each message will be sent without blocking and the responses will be in two futures.  Then you can combine those two futures into one response with a for comprehension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll make a guess you meant an ask instead of a tell because you're
talking about responses, so the code should be

```
def receive = LoggingReceive {
  case HealthReportRequest => log.debug("Generating Health Report")
    println("Generating Health Report")
    versionInfo ? VersionInfoRequest
    memoryInfo ? MemoryInfoRequest
}
```

Then you can type the futures.

```
def receive = LoggingReceive {
  case HealthReportRequest =>
    versionInfo ? VersionInfoRequest mapTo[VersionInfo]
    memoryInfo ? MemoryInfoRequest mapTo[VersionInfo]
}
```

And then combine

```
def receive = LoggingReceive {
  case HealthReportRequest =>
    val version = versionInfo ? VersionInfoRequest mapTo[VersionInfo]
    val memory = (memoryInfo ? MemoryInfoRequest mapTo[VersionInfo])
    version.flatMap(v =>
      memory.map(m =>
        fun(v, m)
    ))
}
```

or via for (not sure on the syntax)

```
def receive = LoggingReceive {
  case HealthReportRequest =>
    val version = versionInfo ? VersionInfoRequest mapTo[VersionInfo]
    val memory = (memoryInfo ? MemoryInfoRequest mapTo[VersionInfo])
    for {
      v <- version
      m <- memory
    } yield fun(v, m)
}
```

Comment: I think you would also want your version and memory requests to be parallel in this case.

Comment: I mean you last code blocks: one with flatMap and Map and one with for comprehension. There you make two sequential requests. The seconds one waits when first is finished.

Comment: You're right on that, got a suggestion how to improve that? `Future.sequence` doesn't apply here.

Comment: I don't know any other way other than initializing you requests first, assigning returning futures to some variables, and then waiting for them in "for {}" block or via map/flatMap.